# How to make a Scanner in Java not care about punctuation

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I know how to make a Java Scanner not care about the uppercase or lowercasing, but how do I make it so that it doesn't care about punctuation? I want to do this so that I don't have to type all of this:

```
if (mirioutput.equalsIgnoreCase("You're an idiot.") ||
    mirioutput.equalsIgnoreCase("Your an idiot.") ||
    mirioutput.equalsIgnoreCase("You're an idiot") ||
    mirioutput.equalsIgnoreCase("Youre an idiot") ||)
{
     //code goes here
}
```

By the way, I'm trying to make a Siri-like program that will respond to what you type, if you're wondering why the text says "You're an idiot."

Comment: Just regex replace it before you make the comparison

Answer (score 2):

you can remove all none alphabatical and digits characters

```
      mirioutput = mirioutput.replaceAll("[^A-Za-Z9-0]","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Scanner's [delimeter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter--) and [findInLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine-java.util.regex.Pattern-) functions.